# can we code inorder,preorder and postorder in single code in python ? without using recursion

Tags: python, binary-tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

i want to code all binary tree orders in single code (preorder,postorder,inorder) in O(N) time complexity and O(N) space , using single stack and without recursion.

anybody can help me ?

Comment: You want  code specifically in python ? or in general the logic will work

Comment: yes, specifically in python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is easy to keep in mind as **we just have to change (3 lines of code)**, order for ***left-root-right*** as we do while using ***recursion***.

Question was asked for Python Implementation, but as Data Structure is language Independent, I am posting this answer so others are benefited.

It is **O(N)** space, using **single stack** and **without recursion**

For ****Inorder Traversal****

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int val;
    node *left, *right;
    node(int x) {
        val = x;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

void traversal_trick(node *root) {
    //inorder
    stack<pair<node*, int>> S;
    
    S.push({root, 0});
    while(!S.empty()){
        pair<node*, int> t = S.top();
        node* cur = t.first;
        int state = t.second;
        
        S.pop();

        if(cur == NULL or state == 3) continue;
        
        S.push({cur, state+1});
        
        if (state == 0) S.push({cur->left, 0});
        else if (state == 1) cout << cur->val << " " ;
        else if (state == 2) S.push({cur->right, 0});
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *root = new node(7); 
    node *t = root;
    root->left = new node(3); root->right = new node(10);
    root->left->left = new node(2); root->left->right = new node(5);
    root->left->left->left = new node(1);
    root->right->left = new node(8); 
    root->right->right = new node(12);
    
    traversal_trick(root);
}
```

For **Preorder Traversal** : Just change this part of code

```
        if (state == 0) cout << cur->val << " " ;
        else if (state == 1) S.push({cur->left, 0});
        else if (state == 2) S.push({cur->right, 0});
```

For **Postorder Traversal** : Just change this part of code

```
        if (state == 0) S.push({cur->left, 0}) ;
        else if (state == 1) S.push({cur->right, 0}) ;
        else if (state == 2) cout << cur->val << " ";
```

For explanation see [this](https://youtu.be/5BzvEmscu-o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack and accompany every pushed node with an order-identification ("pre", "in" or "post"). The code can then check if this matches the required traversal order to decide whether to yield the node's value or not.

Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def traversal(self, order="pre"):
        stack = [(self, "pre")]
        while stack:
            node, nodeorder = stack.pop()
            if nodeorder == order:
                yield node.value
            if nodeorder == "pre":
                stack.append((node, "in"))
                if node.left:
                    stack.append((node.left, "pre"))
            elif nodeorder == "in":
                stack.append((node, "post"))
                if node.right:
                    stack.append((node.right, "pre"))
```

So `traversal` should get as second argument either "pre", "in" or "post", depending on the order you want.

Example tree:

```
         4
        / \
       2   5
      / \   \
     1   3   7
            /
           6
```

...and corresponding code:

```
root = Node(4,
    Node(2,
        Node(1),
        Node(3)
    ),
    Node(5,
        None,
        Node(7,
            Node(6)
        )
    )
)

print(*root.traversal("pre"))   # 4 2 1 3 5 7 6
print(*root.traversal("in"))    # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
print(*root.traversal("post"))  # 1 3 2 6 7 5 4
```

Answer (score 0):

can we code inorder,preorder and postorder in single code in python ? without using recursion

> **Ans.** Yes we can. firstly we intialize a **Stack [LIFO]** with the root and the number. example [(root,1)] number is specifically used to know
> that this is our first time or the second time or the third time we
> visited the node. also intialized the preorder, inorder, postorder to store the answer in a list

Now the main concept we will be using->

> **loop till stack is not empty..!** (1) pop from the stack **[Last in first
> out]** check the value of the number let's say number is 1 than we
> append root val in preorder list and increase the number by 1 and
> appending again in the stack **and if there exist a left (root.left) we
> will append in a stack as well with initializing number by one**.

Lets say the number is 2:

> You will append root val in inorder list and increase the number by 1
> and appending again in the stack **and if there exist a right
> (root.right) we will append in a stack as well with initializing
> number by one**

Lets say the number is 3:

> You will append root val in postorder list. **Note*** when number is 3 **you don't need to again append the root you will simply pop it.. and no need to check whether it has left or right subtree..!**

**That's it this logic we will be using to solve this problem**

**Python Code->**

```
  #Definition for a binary tree node.
    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
    class Solution:
        def preorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
            #In one flow Striver
            stack=[(root,1)]
            pre,ino,post=[],[],[]
            if root==None:
                return
            while stack:
                node,nodepass=stack.pop()
                if nodepass==1:
                    pre.append(node.val)
                    nodepass+=1
                    stack.append((node,nodepass))
                    if node.left!=None:
                        stack.append((node.left,1))
                elif nodepass==2:
                    ino.append(node.val)
                    nodepass+=1
                    stack.append((node,nodepass))
                    if node.right!=None:
                        stack.append((node.right,1))
                else:
                    post.append(node.val)
                
            return pre,ino,post
```

**You can practice this question in** -> https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/problems/981269?topList=striver-sde-sheet-problems&utm_source=striver&utm_medium=website

**Reference video** to more understand about the concepts-> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySp2epYvgTE